# Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'publicKey') in solana

Tags: solana-program, error

```
let tx = await program.methods.initialize(a,b).accounts({
        addAccount: addAccount.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId,
      }).signers([addAccount]).rpc();
```

at user line i am getting error.

Answer (score 3):

Use the variable defined for useAnchorWallet() instead

```
const anchorWallet = useAnchorWallet();

let tx = await program.methods.initialize(a,b)
.accounts({ addAccount: addAccount.publicKey, user: anchorWallet.publicKey, systemProgram: SystemProgram.programId, })
.signers([addAccount]).rpc();
```